# show toast message even fragment is detached?

Tags: android

in my application I have BottomNavigationView use to navigate between five fragment,
frist(supposed called homefragment)  fragment show progressbar while call http request with mvp architecture.
if I navigate to another fragment and the homefragment fished http request and show toast measge the application crash.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the logcat error says :  fragment not attached to a context then,

declare this as global var..

```
private lateinit var appContext: Context
```

and in onCreate() .....

```
appContext = requireContext()
```

and in onAttach()

```
appContext = context
```

lastly .. replace all those requireContext() with appContext in that fragment

Comment: thank @Himanshu Yadav  I am declare private Context context; ant in onAttach() method which is receive Context I assign my context and this is work.